# select drop down using cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.7

```
Controller:
$this->set('project',$this->project->find('list',array('fields' => ('id','name'))));
```

view part:

```
<select>
<option value='1'>Name1</option>
<option value='2'>Name2</option>
<option value='3'>Name3</option>
<option value='4'>Name4</option>
</select>
```

I want view part like above . How to write select dropdown statement using cakephp.Option value is id and view part is project name.

Comment: Why you are adding mutiple cakephp tags?

Comment: value is id value and name is project name . I am displaying project and storing project id .

Comment: The syntax for this has changed in CakePHP 3. It's now `$this->project->find('list', [ 'keyField' => 'id', 'valueField' => 'name'])->toArray()`